# Asm x86 segmentation fault in reading from file

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, mmap

I'm receiving segmentation fault in 5th line of loop2. This is the part of my code which is reading values from mmapped file byte by byte.
Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
.global _start
_start:
    mov $2,%rax
    mov 16(%rsp),%rdi
    mov $02,%rsi
    syscall 

    cmp $0,%rax
    jl exit
1:
    mov %rax,%r8
    mov $9,%rax
    mov $0,%rdi
    mov $4096,%rsi
    mov $0x3,%rdx
    mov $0x1,%r10
    mov $0,%r9
    syscall

    mov $0,%r10
loop2:
    mov (%rax,%r10,1),%r9b
    cmp $32,%r9
    je 2f

    sub $48,%r9b
    mov %r9b,(%r8,%r10,1)

    inc %r10
        jmp loop2
2:
    mov %r10,%rcx
    dec %r10
```

Comment: Assuming you're correct about the 5th line after `loop2`, `(%r8,%r10,1)` evidently refers to an invalid memory address (an address that your program is not allowed to access). If you run the debugger, you can examine the values in the registers to see if they make sense. From the code, it appears that `%r8` was set from `%rax`, and `%r10` is set to `0`. So the value in `%rax` that was used, plus `0`, plus `1` must be a valid address.

Comment: Well, the value (read from (%rax,%r10,1)) in %r9 is 49, which is correct (it's 1 in ASCII, and number in file is 1443).

Comment: And is this address really invalid? The segfault is surely in 5th line, I know it as a result of debugging step by step.

Comment: What's the value of `%r9` before the `mov %r9b,(%r8,%r10,1)` executes?

Comment: As I mentioned before, it's 1.

Comment: Your comment doesn't clearly indicate that 1 was in `%r9` before the `mov`. So `%r9` is `1` before the 5th instruction, and it's `49` after? And the `mov` that puts `49` in to `%r9` is causing the segfault?

Comment: No, 49 is before the sub line. Then it's 1. And mov that is putting 1 into (%r8,%r10,1) is causing the segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in R8 at the time your program crashes is the file descriptor returned by the open syscall. Its value is probably 3 which isn't a valid address. You'll need to stores these values in a range of memory you've properly allocated. You can create a buffer in your program's .bss section or dynamically allocate memory with the brk syscall.

Comment: When I'm trying to add it to buffer: .ascii "00000" this way: mov %r9b,buf(,%r10), also segmentation appears. Furthermore, it appears even if I do mov $0,%r8 before the operation.

Comment: @Fryzjer You've probably allocated the buffer in the .text section which isn't writable. Put it in the .data segment if you want it initialized and writable.